# mySQL ORDER BY temporary calculated column

Tags: mysql, sql, foreach, temp

First you must know:
I have two tables "USERS" and "SONGS"

How is possible to check some conditions and place the result on a temp column?
For example foreach song in result of select must be calculate the bool and add it to temp column so I can do other calculations then and make it the primary order......

```
$USER = SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE SOMECONDITION

SELECT * FROM SONGS
------
(
IF SONGS.LANG  LIKE $USER[LANG]  THEN TEMPCOLUMN.ADD "1" ELSE TEMPCOLUMN.ADD 0
IF SONGS.GENR1 LIKE $USER[GENR1] THEN TEMPCOLUMN.ADD "1" ELSE TEMPCOLUMN.ADD 0
IF SONGS.GENR2 LIKE $USER[GENR2] THEN TEMPCOLUMN.ADD "1" ELSE TEMPCOLUMN.ADD 0
)
------
ORDER BY TEMPCOLUMN DESC
```

Comment: What is `ADD` supposed to do?

Comment: ADD: Adds the zero or one to the end of string.

Comment: Do you only need TEMPCOLUMN for the order?

Comment: Yes, i want to do some calculations to the binary string then and make the order! :)

Comment: Is there a problem with just ordering on the condition?

Comment: The tempcolumn will be a big mix af conditions as one condition adds one digit to the column!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the same thing:

```
SELECT * FROM SONGS
ORDER BY
  SONGS.LANG LIKE $USER[LANG] DESC,
  IF SONGS.GENR1 LIKE $USER[GENR1] DESC,
  IF SONGS.GENR2 LIKE $USER[GENR2] DESC;
```

Comment: So with this way, the songs matches the users language and the songs matches the genre1 and the songs matches the users genre2 came up first?

Comment: I haven't tested it but it should do that.

Comment: Thanks for awnser, also i must ask, this code can place the song that matches the genre1 at the top if no one can match the language?

Comment: Yes. Same for genre2 if there is none with matching lang or genre1.